# Python GTK - Pass mouse click to window below

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, pygtk

I am creating an Ubuntu program that creates a transparent popup window. I would like it to act similarly to the notify-osd popups. When the mouse hovers over the window it fades even more. When the user click the dialog, the event is sent to the window underneath so the user clicks through the popup.

How can I achieve this using Gtk from gi.repository?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

w1 = Gtk.Window() 
w2 = Gtk.Window()

def w2_hide(widget, event):
    w2.set_opacity(0.25)

def w2_show(widget, event):
    w2.set_opacity(0.75)

def w2_click(widget, event):
    w2.hide()

w1.set_size_request(600, 400)
w2.set_transient_for(w1)
w2.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ON_PARENT)

w1.show()
w2.show()
w2_show(w2, None)

w1.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
w2.connect("leave-notify-event", w2_hide)
w2.connect("enter-notify-event", w2_show)
w2.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
w2.connect("button-press-event", w2_click)

Gtk.main()
```